# Using WGET to pull all file names from an index

Tags: wget

I work for a university and I want to pull all the file names of all the PDF catalogs we have and make a text file. These PDFs are all located in an Intranet index. WGET works fine with the intranet and I know how to use it to download a bunch of files from this index. However, I'm doing an audit of our catalogs and I need the file names of each catalog-- not the actual PDF files just the "UniOfState0708.pdf".

All the PDFs are in different directories so Indox of /catalog/ has directories like UniOfStateA/, UniOfStateB/, etc. and each index has PDFs in them and these are the names I want to collect.

Can WGET do this and if so how would I go about it?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You say you can download all files you want but the file names aren't the way you want?

Comment: @WillianPaixaosorry if I was unclear. I do not want the actually files. I'm performing an audit on our catalogs and I need the names of the files. I was wondering if WGET can just give me the names of the files in a `.txt`. 

So I'd run WGET and it would give me a `.txt` with the names of the files, but not the actually PDF.

Comment: There's a option --spider, but I don't see wget as the best tool for that. Maybe a small script in Python.

Comment: You can try rejecting pdf files with `-R '*.pdf'. With `-r` and a server that returns indexes of directories, that might be enough.

Comment: and what is an intranet index ? is it web a server, serving pdf file through a html page ?

Comment: @mazs yes. Just like an index on any website, but only on our University network. We have to keep all documents offline per federal law. It's a mix of html pages, SharePoint sites, and lots of file directories. For the most part we use a program to access the data but it can be accessed over a web browser

Comment: @WillianPaixao yes, I'll try spider. Thought I would give wget a shot before doing anything with python. I am not familiar with any of python's web modules

Comment: i guess you could get the `index.html` of the webserver containing the links to the files, and parse the html file for it's content with `bash`. i'll try to test this locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below solution will only work for a not formatted, standard `apache2` generated directory index. You can `wget` the index file and parse it with `grep` and `cut` for example :

```
#this will download the directory listing index.html file for /folder/
wget the.server.ip.address/folder/   

#this will grep for the table of the files, remove the top line (parent folder) and cut out
#the necessary fields
grep '</a></td>' index.html | tail -n +2 | cut -d'>' -f7 | cut -d'<' -f1
```

Please note, as mentioned above, this will only work if the directory listing is generated by an `apache2` server with basic options, configured like :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/folder>
 Options +Indexes 
 AllowOverride None
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In this configuration, the `wget` will return an `index.html` without any specific formatting, but of course the directory listing can be customized as well, with options :

```
IndexOptions +option1 -option2 ...
```

To offer a more precise answer, which suits your case if that is specific, we would need an example `index.html` file.

And here is also a Python version :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_listing() :
  dir='http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.4.0-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/'
  for file in listFD(dir):
    print file.split("//")[2]

def listFD(url, ext=''):    
  page = requests.get(url).text
  print page
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
  return [url + '/' + node.get('href') for node in soup.find_all('a') if node.get('href').endswith(ext)]

def main() :
  get_listing()


if __name__=='__main__' : 
  main()
```

Used as a guide [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023530/python-to-list-http-files-and-directories).